# AngularJS - Using isolated directive scopes with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular, and am trying to add my own 'selectable' directive to a list, so that an item in the list can either be selected or not. I've been trying to keep it modular, so rather than storing information against the list item, I would rather store it in the scope of the 'selectable' directive.

My HTML:

```
<ul ng-controller="mainCtl">
<li inner="{item: item}" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{sel: inner.selected}">
    {{ item.Name }}
</li>
</ul>
```

My 'inner' directive:

```
    directive('inner', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                inner: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                scope.inner.selected = false;
                element.bind('click', function(e) {
                    scope.inner.selected = !scope.inner.selected;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

As you can see, I'm intending for each row to have a togglable property, which is then used by ngClass to set the element's class, and isn't stored against the 'item' object.

If I select an example list entry, and view what's in the scope, I don't see 'inner' appear at all, so it makes sense that ng-class cannot access it. Chances are I'm trying to go about this the wrong way entirely as I'm not fully used to the 'angular' way of doing things. Any help on how to fix this, or pointing me in the right direction for literature would be helpful.

JSFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2pdvs/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directives are awesome, but do you really need one in this case? You could just do:

```
<ul ng-controller="mainCtl">
    <li ng-click="selected=!selected" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{sel: selected}">
        {{ item.Name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item, so the `selected` variable will exist for each list item independently of each other.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought when I saw what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your directive's both have their own scope, as is. You are setting the bool properly on *their* scope but trying to reference it from the controller scope using `ng-class`.

There are many ways to do this, if you want to keep it within the directive you could simply do this:

```
angular.module('test', []).
    controller('mainCtl', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.items = [{Name: 'obj1'}, {Name: 'obj2'}];
            console.log($scope);
        }]).
    directive('inner', [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    inner: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    var el = angular.element(element);
                    el.on('click', function (a, b, c) {
                        if (el.hasClass('sel')) {
                            el.removeClass('sel');
                        } else {
                            el.addClass('sel');
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/2pdvs/4/

---

**Otherwise I would use @Strille answer**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/TEYTG/

Unlike Asok's answer I still managed to keep `ng-class`. I think your problem was that you weren't passing the right variables and you were using a variable `inner` inside ng-class which was outside its scope (the isolated scope of the directive).

**Edit**

This is a proposed alternative approach without using directives and it's still very blurry so I just give pseudo-code. The idea is to create some kind of factory that takes arrays and attaches some kind of selection logic to them.

```
app.service('selection', [function(){
    function selection(array){
       //constructor function that attaches or creates the selection logic for the array
    }


    this.create = function(input){
        return new selection(input);
    }
}]);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['selection', '$scope', function(selection, $scope){
    $scope.array = [{...},{...}];


    //Creates a selection from the array
    $scope.selection=selection.create($scope.array);
}])
```

The idea is that the `selection` function inside the service would take the array and attach the selection logic to it (i.e. attach a `selected=false` property to each object, make a function that allows to toggle selection of one object, a function to deselect all items, or determining if at least some elements in the array are selected)

Although this may seem a lot more complicated (it is) I believe it has the advantage of being easily re-usable whenever you want to be a able to select from a list.

Comment: Note that manually calling [$apply()](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) is considered bad practise in most cases and is very rarely needed, there's often a more elegant solution.

Comment: True, but if we're using the jQuery lite library ('element.bind()'), angular doesn't naturally call $scope.$apply() like in many other cases. Alternatively I could have created the same functionality using an 'ng-click' like in your example, and I wouldn't have had to use $apply()

Comment: @Strille's answer is definitely more simple and I agree that using directives is overkill. However, hopefully you understand a bit better how directive scopes work. In my project I've been thinking of creating some kind of selection service/factory that would create a selection for any array. In keeping true with Angular it should be re-usable and be independent of the interface. If I have something interesting I'll share.